# What happens if I format a mounted USB drive with --force flag?

Tags: usb-drive, mkfs

It occurred that I typed `-F` (`--force`) instead of `-f` (`--fast`) while running `mkfs.ntfs` command. The USB drive was mounted. What are possible consequences to the drive?

There's also a message "Hope /etc/mtab is incorrect". What does it mean?

Comment: That the developer has a sense of humor. It's probably just saying that it checks `mtab` first and `-F` overrides this for cases where `mtab` actually is incorrect.

Comment: It is saying that it is mounted. So there could be problems, the contents of the device may become inconsistent, or a badly written file-system-driver could crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what you have done by using `mkfs.ntfs -F /dev/sdb` or whatever against that flash disk is that you have forced upon the flash disk an `ntfs` partition.

The alert you are getting and this is just my hunch here is because you mounted it as `vfat` in `/etc/mtab` then forced an overwrite of the file system using `ntfs`. Although that's just speculative.

Always unmount before making any filesystem changes to avoid that error.